# Disable button when no internet connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, internet-connection

How do I disable a button when there is no connection to a network / internet in iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the reachability code from Apple.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

and use it like this:

```
Reachability *reachabilityInstance = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
[reachabilityInstance startNotifier];
NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachabilityInstance currentReachabilityStatus];
BOOL connected = (networkStatus==ReachableViaWiFi || networkStatus==ReachableViaWWAN);
```

Comment: well i dont want the notification and all the stuff, just a simple test and condition so i can disable the button

Comment: Reachability is the way to go, just implement the part you need.

Comment: and how to disable the button?

Comment: I've added a code example and use: `button.isEnabled = connected;`

Please don't forget to upvote and accept my answer if you use it.

Comment: tried it with syncButton.isEnabled = connected; but says that "setter method is needed to assign ..."

Comment: I might have the method `.isEnabled` wrong. Try `[syncButton set..]` and see what auto complete options are there are.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply hide a button whenever you need to

```
[button setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: simple check condition when internet is not available and in that button.hidden = YES;

Comment: I think you want userInteraction so you want button.userInteractionEnable = NO;

Comment: thats the same as [syncButton setEnabled:NO]